# object DOMWindow - chrome

Tags: function, google-chrome

i have problem with google-chrome,
i have normal function like this `function a(b){ return b; }`
but if i have in my code this `var number=a(5);document.write(number);` google chrome says me  [object DOMWindow]

in FF it works good where is problem?
thanks

Comment: Impossible. Show a demo, because your current code [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/XFftx/).

Comment: it was possible, but problem was that my var name was "top" and chrome doesnt accept it(i dont know why) so i rename it to topA and it works

Comment: That is a significant detail, please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) is a **read-only** global variable which refers to the topmost `window` object in the current page. Because it's read-only, you can't assign a new value to it:

```
var top = 1;
console.log(top); // [object DOMWindow]
```

The assignment silently failed. Though, when [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) is activated, then a TypeError is thrown, which indicates that you're attempting to set a property that has only a getter:

```
"use strict";
var top = 1; // <-- Error!
```

The previous happens, because the code runs in the global context. However, when you **[declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)** the variable **locally** (ie, not global), then the function works:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var top = 1;
    return top;
})(); // Returns 1, no errors.
```